# Calcular edad en Java 7

Tags: java, java-7

Quisiera calcular la edad en Java de la siguiente manera PERO EN JAVA 7:

```
import java.time.LocalDate; 
import java.time.Period; 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
LocalDate fechaNac = LocalDate.parse("15/08/1993", fmt); 
LocalDate ahora = LocalDate.now();

Period periodo = Period.between(fechaNac, ahora); 
System.out.printf("Tu edad es: %s años, %s meses y %s días",
                    periodo.getYears(), periodo.getMonths(), periodo.getDays());
```

En Java 7 aún no está habilitado el método Period y quisiera saber si existe otro método que me calcule los días faltantes para llegar a una fecha o algún algoritmo similar que tengan.

Quisiera una salida como esta:

```
Tu edad es: 22 años, 9 meses y 29 días
```

Lo vi tan fácil con ese método de `Period` pero al intentarlo hacer me cuesta un poco.

Comment: Tenes que usar las clases Date, Calendar, y SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Se que con clases puedo obtener los días, meses y años vividos pero quisiera tener como resultado cuantos días me faltan para cumplir otro mes de vida. Gracias por responder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacer una serie de restas usando Date, Calendar y Gregorian Calendar. Te comparto el código que realicé hace algún tiempo, creo que te puede servir.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test{
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Calendar birthDay = new GregorianCalendar(2000, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 12);
        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(); 
        today.setTime(new Date()); 
        int yearsInBetween = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birthDay.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
        int monthsDiff = today.get(Calendar.MONTH) - birthDay.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
        if (monthsDiff <=0){
            yearsInBetween--;
            monthsDiff =  monthsDiff + 12 ;
        }
        int daysDiff = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - birthDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (daysDiff < 0){
            if (monthsDiff > 0)
               monthsDiff--;
            Calendar aux = new GregorianCalendar(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            aux.set(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            daysDiff = aux.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - birthDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +  today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Sir James Gosling's age : " + yearsInBetween +" years " + monthsDiff + " meses " + daysDiff+ " dias");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que buscaba.

Comment: si la respuesta te ayudo por favor marcala como solución así aumenta tu puntuación y la mía, saludos.